# get Value DataPicker and Radio Button

Tags: c#, wpf

i want to create advence search but i have problem to get RadioButton Value and DataPicker Value .

this is my Xml Code :

```
 <PersianDateControls:PersianDatePicker Name="DateEndPicker" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,470,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Background="White" Height="25" Grid.Column="2"/>
   <PersianDateControls:PersianDatePicker Name="DateStartPicker" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,418,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" Background="White" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="Rad_Active" Content="Active" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="407,433,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Iranian Sans"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="Rad_DeActive" Content="DeActive" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="272,433,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Iranian Sans"/>
```

how can i solve this problem ?

```
private void btn_search_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        string Name = txt_Name.Text;
        string Family = txt_family.Text;

        var QSearch = db.Tbl_User.Where(u => u.Name == Name).Where(u => u.Family == Family).ToList();
        dataGrid.ItemsSource = QSearch;
    }
```

show me this error when i using this code for compate to date

**Edit**

When i Use The RadioButton Show me this Error

```
bool Active;
if (Rad_Active.IsChecked) // Error 1 here
{
    Active = true;
}
else if (Rad_DeActive.IsChecked) // Error 1 here
{
    Active = false;
}
```

Error 1

> Cannot implicitly convert type "bool?" to "bool".

#### Edit 2

```
DateTime Date = DateEndPicker.SelectedDate; // Error 2 here
```

Error 2

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Arash.PersianDate' to 'System.DateTime'

#### Edit 3

```
PersianDate DateEnd = DateEndPicker.SelectedDate;
PersianDate DateStart = DateEndPicker.SelectedDate;

var QSearch = db.Tbl.User.Where(u => u.Name == Name)
    .Where(u => u.Family == Family)
    .Where(u => u.Active == Active)
    .Where(u => u.DateReg >= DateStart && u.DateReg <= DateEnd).ToList(); // Error 3 here
dataGrid.ItemsSource = QSearch
```

Error 3

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS0019  Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DateTime' and 'PersianDate'    AnbarDari   F:\MyProject\AnbarDari\AnbarDari\Win_Users.xaml.cs  77  Active

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I can not get into the values

Comment: I don't see that you've tried anything to get the values. What have you tried to retrieve values from the DatePickers and/or RadioButtons?

Comment: problem is here . i dont know how do this

Comment: RadioBox properties can can easily looked up [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx). As for the PersianDatePicker, I'm assuming it would work like DatePicker. If so, you can lookup the properties [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: show me error . update question

Comment: Can you please post the errors as text rather than screen shots. It makes working out what's going on much, much simpler.

Comment: But is it of type `DateTime` or `PersianDate`?

Comment: persiandate calender

Comment: `DateReg` is obviously acting as a `DateTime` object and it won't let you compare between `DateTime` and `PersianDate`. Also, please post all errors in text instead of images. I can't look at anymore images without my head exploding.

Comment: sorry man . i put the error

Comment: Can you add your initialization of `DateReg` to the post?

Comment: `2016-09-01 00:00:00.000`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125757/discussion-between-kianoush-and-hank).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into just one radio button. Just set `bool? Active = Rad_Active.IsChecked`
This will set your active flag based on the status of that single checkbox.

Comment: but i have to question . how get datapicker value ?

Comment: To get the DatePicker value, look into `DatePicker.SelectedDate`. It will either return `null` or a value in the DateTime format.

Comment: Try `PersianDate Date = DateEndPicker.SelectedDate;`I was unable to find the documentation for that library so I was unsure how it would return.

Answer (score 0):

As `IsChecked` is a nullable bool you can't just do a straight cast. If it's null the cast will fail. Instead you can do this:

```
if (Rad_Active.IsChecked == true)
{
    Active = true;
}
```

As for converting between a `PerisanDate` and a regular `DateTime` there will be a method or property that returns a regular `DateTime`, but without knowing exactly which picker you are using it's hard to give a definitive answer. The IDE should be able to give you some clues via autocomplete or viewing the definition of the class (in Visual Studio, right click -> Go to definition)